# Pygame: Get an image from the average mixture of multiple images

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have an number of images with the same resolution in a list... they're generated and painted from the code with with `pygame.Surface` though that shouldn't be relevant for this question, will mention they're part of a multi-sampling system with each image representing one render. I want to merge them into a single image, with the resulting image being the average of all images on all channels (RGBA). How can I most efficiently achieve this?

Obviously I can't just blit the two as `img1.blit(img2, (0, 0))` as the later image will fully cover the former. I do use an alpha channel for other purposes, which allows mixing future images at a lower transparency on top of the previous result, but this isn't accurate as I want a real average without later images covering the result by a variable amount based on order: I don't want the result to look like `img1.* / 2 + img2.* / 2 + img3.* / 2` but rather `(img1.* + img2.* + img3.*) / 3`.

I'm aware I could manually scan the pixels in each image but that would be very performance intensive: I'd prefer using the using less accurate alpha blending than having to saddle the main loop with that. Please let me know what is the closest solution you're aware of.

Answer (score 2):

> but that would be very performance intensive

I don't understand your remark at all.

Start by importing [a library](https://pypi.org/project/numpy):

```
import numpy as np
```

Then fetch the pixels from those three images:

```
    img1 = np.array( ... )  # wherever you're storing the pixels
    img2 = ...
    img3 = ...
    assert img1.shape == img2.shape == img3.shape
    assert img1.shape[1] == 3  # three color channels -- consider dropping the alpha channel
```

Now you're ready to go, exactly as OP suggested,
but vectorized for very fast speed:

```
    mean_img = (img1 + img2 + img3) / 3.
```

Finally, convert that
[ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.html)
so pygame can conveniently display it.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm aware I could manually scan the pixels in each image but that would be very performance intensive

That's true, but technically this is the only way - each calculation has to be performed for each pixel, but you know that there are ways for optimizing this. First and most obvious is not using python, but that's not a good answer.

Regarding your idea with using blend flags - that's not a bad idea, but there is no `BLEND_RGB_DIV` flag.

Using numpy to add the images and divide per pixel is not a bad idea, but there are possible improvements that we can implement: firstly converting an image to numpy array is a bit time-consuming operation, second of, pygame(-ce), if can, will use vector instructions (smid) for blitting.

I think that the fastest solution, that isn't over-complicated, is something like this:

```py
import pygame as pg
import numpy as np

...

images = [image1, image2, image3, ...]
output = pg.Surface(images[0].get_size())

for image in images:
    output.blit(image, (0, 0), special_flags=pg.BLEND_RGB_ADD)
    

# Create reference to output
array = pg.surfarray.pixels3d(output)
#  Divide in-place
array //= len(images)
# Unlock surface
del array

return output
```

On average I get about 2x improvement over:

```py
...

# Create reference to output
array = pg.surfarray.pixels3d(output)

for image in images:
    array += pg.surfarray.pixels3d(image)

...
```

The issues that you might notice sometimes are: image data loss or errors because of overflowing (ie 255 + 255 won't result in 510 and afterwards neatly divided by 2 returning 255, but instead 255 + 255 will give 255 and after division, it will be 127). You can prevent this by casting the array to a bigger integer type (like uint32, instead of current uint8), but it will impact performance, as code no longer will just keep reference to image data, but it'll have to use more time-consuming function that copies the data. Here is my implementation of this:

```py
...

images = [image1, image2, image3, ...]
output = pg.Surface(images[0].get_size())

# Create reference to the output surface.
array = pg.surfarray.pixels3d(output)
# Copy data from output surface to another numpy array, now with uint32 instead of uint8
array32 = array.astype(np.uint32)

# Add images
for image in images:
    array32 += pg.surfarray.pixels3d(image)

# Perform now more detailed division.
array32 //= len(images)

# Copy the data back.
np.copyto(array, array32)

# Remove references and unlock output surface.
del array, array32

...
```

In my opinion the last solution is the best, as even though is the slowest one, it doesn't break that easily and it runs fast enough that you shouldn't notice any difference (and you can always cache the results to not recalculate them every frame).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `pg.transform.average_surfaces` which does exactly what I need when used in the correct order.

https://pyga.me/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.average_surfaces